# write generic function in javascript to take multiple params from other function as single argument and pass those arguments to some other functions

Tags: javascript

I need help in writing a generic javascript function. This function will be called from many of the functions passing different number of arguments. Suppose function a1, a2 call this generic function.

```
function a1() {
    _genericFunction(methodname, var1, var2);
}

function a1() {
    _genericFunction(methodname, var1, var2, var3);
}
```

This `_genericFunction` should call another method passing those params.

```
function _genericFunction(methodname, args) {
    someObj[methodname](args);    //methodname = add
}
```

And those methods like add should be able to access parameters those are passed through `args`.

Can this be achieved using javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you should try this

```
function a1() {
    _genericFunction(methodname, var1, var2);
}

function a1() {
    _genericFunction(methodname, var1, var2, var3);
}

function _genericFunction() {
  if(arguments.length > 0){  
        someObj["'" + arguments[0] + "'"](arguments.slice(0,1));    
  }
}
```

in a javascript function you can inspect input parameters in an array called arguments

The slice() method resize the array from first parameter input index end remove second parameter input items.

Comment: arguments is not an array object. How would 'shift' method work on it?